# Cohomologies of $\mathbb R^n$ with rational differential forms

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, homology-cohomology

We can consider de Rham complex $0 \to \Omega^1 \to \Omega ^ 2 \to...$ on $\mathbb R^n$, where $\Omega ^r$ are $r$-forms on $\mathbb R^n$ with rational coefficients. What are homologies of this complex? Is there a good theory for it?
Fow example, if we consider $\mathbb R^1$, then $H^0=0$, but $H^1$ is infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb R$. I want to calculate homologies of $\mathbb R^n$ when $n \geq 2$.